# How to fit a "multi-nomial" expression with negative powers to an (x,y) dataset?

Tags: functions, polynomials

I understand that a "Polynomial" expression for $y = f(x)$ is retricted to powers of $x$ greater than zero.

I have a dataset of ($x,y$) data pairs which I want to express in the form of (what I in ignorance of a better term call) a "Multi-nomial" expression of the form:-

```
 y(x) = A + B/x + C/x*x + D/x*x*x...
```

Is there a method or algorithm available for finding a best-fit to a dataset in the form of such a "Multi-nomial" negative-powers expression?

Comment: Calculate columns $1/x$, $1/x^2$ $ \cdots$ , then do a multivariate regression of $y$ against these.

Comment: @Donald Splutterwit. Ah thanks, that works well in MS Excel Data Analysis. Minor point: I read that Single Dependent Variable ==> "Multiple Regression" (not Multivariate Regression).

Comment: Cool $ \ddot \smile$ ... I am glad it has worked out.